# Add 'My Location' button to search locations input

Tags: buttons, search, input, location

me and my team trying to figure out where is the optimal and most intuitive location to place 'My Location' button related to a search areas auto complete input.

As part of our current design, the user has 3 inputs:
[image: search input, time input, tags inputs]

Our functionality dictates that the user will be able to choose his own location or to choose an area from auto complete feature connected to google maps. One suggested solution was to place the 'My Location' button as the first option in the areas drop down, but since we want to let the user know that he can use his current location before even typing, we got into some trouble here deciding the correct area to place the button, and also couldn't find any solution on the web.

We are open for using button with text 'My Location' or just an Icon, as long as its well understood - our target audience are at ages 15 to 45 (mostly 18-28).

Thanks a lot for reading

Answer (score 1):

Map pin always to indicate a location. in your case 'Where'. instead of where you can use 'use my location' if the user does not want to use the current location user will click and select the location. And it's better to have a map showing area. So user can identify my where is currently in.

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your quick response.
Currently we don't have any space to place a map underneath the input, but your idea to use user's current location by default is interesting.
One problematic use case - If the user chose a location from drop down and wants to get back to current location, how could this be accomplished?

Comment: @RanRoslanBobkov you can have it from the dropdown menu. 
Please refer the link: https://imgur.com/2fv8vJt

Comment: first off thanks for the effort. We think that this solution might fail in th following case: If the user types a location, and afterwards want to change to his current location - clicking back on the input won't trigger a drop down with various locations since there is nothing to autocomplete - the location is already typed. If the user deletes the text, this will also won't trigger a drop down since we're not sending empty string to Google.. Therefore this will will need to open a drop down with only one option: my location, which seems to us a bit odd